# Access variable in class

Tags: php, arrays, class, variables

i would like to access an variable, which is in an class (not as an instance of an class)
For example

```
class myclas
{
private $list=array('1','2','3');
[...]
}
```

I need to access the values of $list in that way: myclass::$list (witch is'n possible).
Is there an alternative way?

Thank you.

//Edit: Thank you all for the answer! Is it possible to use an private variable as values for an public?

```
class myclas
 {
   private $_list=array('1','2','3');
   public static $staticList=$_list;
  [...]
    }
```

Right now, i get an error "unexpected T_VARIABLE"

Comment: Instead of create a public variable that reads from the private, create a public statc function that reads from the private variable. You then call the function: myclass::myfunction()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class myclas
{
public static $list=array('1','2','3');
}
myClass::$list;
```

Comment: if you want to limit access to variable make it private and create static method like public static getList() { return self::$list; }

Answer (score 3):

See this beautiful guide: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

It's a private variable. If you made it a public static variable you should be able to access it:

```
class myclas {
 public static $list = array('1','2','3');
}

myclas::$list;
```

Comment: If you want to keep your variable private, you can write a public static function to extract the values and return them. That might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be declared as [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Example:

```
class MyClass {

    public static $var = 'foo';
}
```

Then to access: `MyClass::$var;`

Answer (score 0):

For your edit, see this other beatiful guide about classes and visibility:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: thank you for all that beautiful links. This one, I still know. But i was not able to project this guide on my problems... so i'm happy to find some help here.