# How to get a class-global variable in PHP?

Tags: php, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access variable in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058814/access-variable-in-class)

I'm building some caching functionality for a class and would like a "class-global" array, i.e. an array that is the same in all instances but not constant. How can this be done?

Comment: `public static $someName` :? Whats the concrete problem you achieved? Btw: It's a "static property", not a "class-global variable" ;)

Comment: you are probably looking for class static variable http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Ooh, I _was_ using `static`, but also a local variable (`$CACHE` instead of `MyClass::$CACHE`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your solution is a `static` variable!

```
<?php
// ...
class Foo {
  public static $array;


  public static function addValue($key, $value) {
    self::$array[$key] = $value;
  }

  public static function getArrayKey($key) {
    if(isset(self::$array[$key])) {
      return self::$array[$key];
    }
  }
}

Foo::addValue('foo', 'bar');
echo(Foo::getArrayKey('foo'));
// ...
?>
```

Comment: At least mention something about global variables being evil.

Comment: @Truth that was not the question...

Comment: It wasn't but it's worth mentioning as extra information. When I give an answer of which the only solution is evil, I specify it in the answer. (In bold, italized, large, gray-background, capitalized letters actually :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with static variables.

But you honestly shouldn't, because global state isn't good.

if you must, it would look something like:

```
class SomeClass
{
    static public $var = array();
}
```

You'd access it with `self::$var` or `static::$var` from within the class itself or a subclass, and `SomeClass::$var` or $`instanceOfSomeClass::$var` from outside.

Comment: How could cached SQL results be anything but global?

Comment: You only need a particular result for the bits of the system where that information is relevant.  The rest of the system doesn't need to know, and it can cause real problems later on if parts of a system that shouldn't have access to particular data actually do.  It also introduces a multitude of other problems.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: ..which is why I'm putting it in the relevant class.

Comment: If you do it as a static then it's globally available, especially if it's global static.

Comment: @Andreas: You wrap it appropriately in a wrapper class, which keeps all instances of your classes, plus it saves the cached value as a field inside of it. That way it's accessible to all instances, but not to anyone else.